# How to send Okta SAML response to frontend?

Tags: redirect, saml-2.0, okta

I've a React frontend and a nestJS backend. I've already configured most of the things related to SAML. My confusion is when Okta uses the callback to send the SAML response to my backend, how do I notify the frontend that the user is authenticated or not.

Request - Response flow:

- Frontend requests for Okta Login
- Backend redirects the browser to okta login page
- Okta posts on the callback
- Backend matches the response with the certificate and redirect the browser to my site.

The initial request with the frontend already ended when I redirected the user to the Okta login page. Now how do I inform frontend about this authentication so that frontend can store the access tokens and other informations??

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you backend can remember the initial URI which user requested, which caused a redirect to Okta, and save it into RelayState parameter, when making Okta SAML authentication request. Okta will return the same value when doing SAML assertion post/redirect back to your backend. So your backend can return a user to the intended page after verifying SAML response.